# Why are the 9 patch not working at all in my app?

Tags: android, imageview, nine-patch, stretch

I am currently trying to use 9 patch pictures in my app.

The image is quite clear and work pretty well in the graphic tool provided with SDK:

Picture is like this:

[image]

and the tool seems to work fine:

[image]

Unfortunately, with such a simple layout, the rendering is bad on a device and the 9 patch does not work at all:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/platenumber"
    android:background="@drawable/plate_fr"
    android:layout_width="320dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

[image]

**EDIT:**

My picture is named *.9.png

[image]

Comment: It looks like the containers you are using are a width of `fill parent` size.  Have you tried using a width more akin to the size you'd like the 9-patch to be?

Comment: what is the name of your 9 patch file?it had to looks like "pic.9.png"

Comment: its not properly saved as .9.png.

Comment: Thabk a lot for all the comments, but as you can see in my edit, the fils is a .9.png

Comment: Are the black lines totally black?(RGB:#000000) and the transparent zone totally transparent?
It allready happen to me

Comment: @VinceFR, yes, I double checked the colors and transparency!

Comment: weird...could you upload your pic somewhere?I will try it

Comment: Just triple checked... and accepted your answer ;-)

Comment: how do you fixed this Problem??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The black lines have to be totally black(RGB:#000000) and the transparent zone around black lines totally transparent.

Comment: "the transparent zone around black lines totally transparent" +1 for this.

Comment: din't get what u r trying to say...can u pls elaborate??i am having the same problem.

Comment: which black lines and transparent zone do you refer to? when you say black line, if you mean black lines on left, right, top and bottom provided by 9patch, mine are totally black and still my 9patch image renders very bad on my device but shows very good on my layout design.

Answer (score 6):

The extention of your 9-patch image should end with  **.9.png** or it will be taken as a normal image

Comment: As you can see in the edit I added in my question... the image end with .9.png

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have at least **one black pixel** on all **four sides** of your images.